# How to use useEffect to get data from redux using useSelector @redux/toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, web3js, redux-toolkit

i am working on a pet-shop react Dapp, at certain point the requirement is to auto refresh pet adopters list.. so for this i have tried useEffect with useSelector to get the data from store... but the problem is it is running and i can see it in my console but it doesn't refresh the list. to get the updated list i need to refresh the page which is not a good idea.

**Problem**

i open two same UI tabs, on UI one i am adopting a pet it updates the adopters list and hide the button of adopt pet, but the same time second UI doesn't updated automatically, if i need to see any updates i must refresh the UI(page) to get updates.

i want it to just refresh the list without refreshing the whole page, only a specific part of the page updates no need to refresh the whole page...

**adoptionSlice.js**

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import Web3 from "web3";
import Adoption from '../contracts/Adoption'

export const initWeb3 = createAsyncThunk(
    'InitWeb3',
    async (a, thunkAPI) => {
        console.log('initWeb3 a: ', a)
        console.log('initWeb3 thunkapi: ', thunkAPI)
        console.log('initWeb3 dispatch: ', thunkAPI.dispatch)
        try {

            if (Web3.givenProvider) {
                const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider)
                await Web3.givenProvider.enable();
                web3.eth.handleRevert = true;

                const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
                const network = Adoption.networks[networkId];
                const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(Adoption.abi, network.address)
                const addresses = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
                thunkAPI.dispatch(loadAdopters({
                    contract: contract,
                    address: addresses[0]
                }))
                console.log(addresses)

                return {
                    web3: web3,
                    contract: contract,
                    address: addresses[0],
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log('Error In Loading Web3')
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('Error In Loading')
        }
    }
)

// export const loadAdopters = createAsyncThunk(
//     'LoadAdopters',
//     async (a, thunkAPI) => {
//         console.log('in loadAdopters a = ', a);
//         console.log('in loadAdopters thunkApi = ', thunkAPI);
//         console.log('in loadAdopters thunkApi state = ', thunkAPI.getState());
//         const contract = thunkAPI.getState().adoptReducer.contract;
//         console.log('loadadopters contract = ', contract);
//         const adopterList = await contract.methods.getAdopters().call()
//         return adopterList
//     }
// )
export const loadAdopters = createAsyncThunk(
    "LoadAdopters",
    async(data,thunkAPI)=>{
        const adopterList = await data.contract.methods.getAdopters().call();
        return adopterList;
    }
)

const adoptSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'AdoptSlice',
    initialState: {
        web3: null,
        contract: null,
        address: null,
        adopters: [],
        adoptInProgress: false,
        adopError: false,
        adoptErrorMessage: '',
        releasingPetStatus: false,
        releasePetError: '',
        releaseErrorMessage: ''
    },
    reducers: {
        adopt: () => { }
    },
    extraReducers: {
[initWeb3.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            console.log("In fullfil = ", state);
            console.log("In fullfil = ", action);
            state.web3 = action.payload.web3;
            state.contract = action.payload.contract;
            state.address = action.payload.address;
        },
        [loadAdopters.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
            state.adopters = action.payload
        },
}

export const adopReducer = adoptSlice.reducer;
export const { adopt } = adoptSlice.actions;
```

> **adoptionSlice.js** for loading web3 and to get loadAdopters

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  const web3 = useSelector((state)=>{
    console.log("state in app= ",state);
    return state.adoptReducer.web3
  })
 
  useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(initWeb3());
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  },[])

  return (
    <div>
      <PetList></PetList>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Adopter.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { loadAdopters } from '../store/adoptSlice'

export const Adopters = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const adoptersList = useSelector((state) => {
        return state.adoptReducer.adopters
    })

    useEffect(() => {

        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            dispatch(loadAdopters())
            console.log('updated')
        }, 2000)
        return () => clearInterval(interval)
    }, [])
    return (
        <div>
            <div>Adopters List</div>
            <div>
                {
                    adoptersList.map((list, index) => (
                        list !== '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000' ? <div key={index}>index {index} : {list}</div> : null
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

> **Adopter.js** to get the list of adopters from store

[image: this is the adopters list]

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are trying to achieve is not possible with what you have explained. There are mainly two problems.

- When you open a same react app on two different tabs, its essentiality two different instance of the app, which shares nothing in common. Each of it has its own state, redux,etc.
- What can be understood from your problem is you want that whenever an action is done that changes/updates your value in some DB, you want it to be reflected across other users. This is not possible if you are **NOT**
- a. continuosly calling the api explicitly,

  b. using some libraries that silently calls the api for you and
  update the state (eg, SWR)

  c. using any pub/sub model (eg signalR)

So, you should try to think and solve the second problem first, which will automatically solve the first one.

Comment: yeah alright, but i just want to get a small piece of information from store and use that on the page...so useEffect hook should do this??

Comment: You should read about useSelector if you want a data from store asynchronously.